# Where to save profile type?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I my application there are two types of profiles for one user.

I need to make switch between profiles.

Where to store profile type? Session or cookie?

Comment: What is a profile in your application context?

Comment: This is integer type that defines type profile(1 or 2)

Comment: Session, cookie, table, carrier pigeon -- it's your choice really. Is there something specific you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: I think about relatable way, I think session as case can be